# Recommended setup procedure for Apple Magic Trackpad gestures?

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch

I have an Apple Magic Trackpad, and I wish to use it with multitouch gestures in Ubuntu. Doing a search returns pages which are several years old and have conflicting advices (synaptic, ginn, touchegg, etc...), while even mentioning that ginn is unstable.

But, today, in late 2016, what's the recommended way of having it working in Ubuntu? Note that I prefer [out of the box it just works]-type solutions rather than dark hacks or weird tools installations that can break default Ubuntu behavior.

I wish to have 3-finger dragging for dragging windows (and for emulating left mouse button dragging in applications), 2-finger scrolling, 2-finger tap for right click, and 2-finger zooming and rotating would be nice too (if Unity supports them, which I don't know).

Comment: I've been searching and haven't seen any good solutions yet myself